# Rails tables in different languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I'm building a multilang application, which should be support French and Flemish (there are multiple models/tables; but these two can change in the future, it needs to be dynamic)

So I want the ability to display the same "attribute" with more than a language, for example, consider a category called **Cars**. Lets say that it should have a color in french & flemish (amongst other characteristics).

I'm assuming the Model would stay the same, but maybe in the database it would be something like this (I don't know if it's possible)

```
#<Model id: 4, name: "Model 4", color:"{fr: "noir", nl:"zwart"}">
```

This is an example of how the its seen from the view:[1]

As you can see, the idea's not to create two `Models`, one in each language, for that one to contain information in both languages.

The value cannot be predicted really, the user could add any type of value (it's a free form string), so I don't think I18N and manually maintained translation tables would be a good fit.

Thank you

Comment: What are your thoughts on Rails Internationalization (I18n) API? Link: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I suggest looking at a gem like [globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize).

Comment: Is the color a free form string or is it one of a fixed set of values? If the former then something like globalize, otherwise I18N and manually maintained translation tables would fit.

Comment: The value is not set, it could be anything (it's a free form string), so there's no way to know what the user will write

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about saving in the database a string of a language that you prefer, for example using english:

```
#<Model id: 4, name: "Model 4", color: "black" >
```

And to translate to the language that you what, you will need to create a yml file for that inside `config/locales` folder, for example:

```
fr:
  color:
    black: noir
```

The name of this file should be `fr.yml`.

With that it would be possible to call `I18n` when the locale is "fr":

```
I18n.t "color.#{car.color}"
```

And it should return: "noir". You'll need to create a yml file for every language used in your app.

For more information take a look at the rails documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: This only works when `color` is a fixed set of values. but if the user is able to enter any text into the color field and therefore the translation needs to be dynamic too than this method doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is that the user should be able to save any value, it's not set value
It could be anything really, but there's no way to know which value they'll decide to write.